# Correct way to "merge" two custom listview adapters

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using a custom listview adapter to connect a listview to a database. However I'd like to add endless list functionality to the listview. I've found another custom listview adapter here https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless which implements the endless functionality i'm looking for.

Now what's the ideal way to integrate these two adapters? Should I make my current listview adapter a sub-class of the endless one? i.e. BaseAdapter -> EndlessListAdapter -> MyCustomListAdapter. Would this even work? As they'll be duplicate overridden methods.

Comment: Did you read the instructions on the Web page that you linked to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded the demo app of [cwac-endless](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)? They have a demo, and this demo answer your question, as it have a class called [DemoAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/endless/demo/DemoAdapter.java) that overrides EndlessAdapter. :)
Also, take a look at [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless#cwac-endlessadapter-it-just-keeps-going-and-going-and)

> "To use EndlessAdapter, you need to create a subclass that will control
>   the endlessness, specifying what View to use for the "loading"
>   placeholder, and then updating that placeholder with an actual row
>   once data has been loaded."